# Frame Support in Heroku for Octopress

Tags: heroku, octopress

When I submit my blog articles to [dzone](http://www.dzone.com/links/index.html) they don't show up because dzone puts the article in a frame.  I have no frame busting code on my site and after talking to dzone support it was made clear that it is a setting on Heroku.  Doing some more research I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434095/facebook-page-tab-doesnt-show-my-content).

It seems logical that I need to do the same thing, however, I don't have an app.rb file, that I know of, because Octopress generates a bunch of HTML that is uploaded to Heroku.  And I'm just using the free Heroku account.  Is there a way for me to adjust the protection settting?

I realize this might not be a question for this site.  Possibly [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)? I just don't know exactly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something you should do in Javascript. Perhaps this will be helpful to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller

Comment: No, this is not a javascript issue.  It is a protection setting on the server that is sending a header back in the response.  I need to change this but I'm not a ruby guru and I don't know where/how to make the necessary change suggested by the link I gave in my question.